# Combine Histogram and Cumulative Distribution Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

How do I overlay the cumulative distribution of some data over a histogram of the same data?
I have the following code:

```
DistributionData=Results(end,:);
figure(4)
clf
nbins = 100;
hist(DistributionData,nbins)
hold on
cdfplot(DistributionData)
hold off
```

But because the cdf is on a different scale I need to have that on a second y-axis. Ideally I want to plot the inverse cdf also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
a = randn(1000,1);
f = figure;
a1 = axes('Parent',f);
hist(a)
a2 = axes('Parent',f);
cdfplot(a)
grid off
set(a2,'Color','none')
set(a2,'YAxisLocation','right')
```

[image]

It's not perfect (for example, the tick marks on right and left axes are superimposed), and I haven't tidied up the title and axis labels, but perhaps that's a good start.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Do you know, out of interest, how to place the stats for the histogram on the graph itself?

Comment: By "the stats for the histogram", do you mean things such as the mean, standard deviation etc? If so, then my approach would be to first calculate the quantities of interest using the commands `mean`, `std` etc, and then to place them directly on to the graph. You could put them in the title using the `title` command, or place them within the graph using the command `text`.

Comment: should consider using plotyy also